# Doctrine 2 How to add Subquery in FROM

Tags: doctrine-orm

I am trying to add a Subquery in a FROM in Doctrine 2 Querybuilder. My SQL looks like this:
(this is a simplified example)

```
SELECT 
  u.username, sub1.totalPosts
FROM usertbl u
  (SELECT  SUM(posts_qty) AS totalPosts,user_id FROM poststbl p 
WHERE p.user_id = 5) sub1,
  usertbl u 
LEFT JOIN location o ON u.location_id = l.location_id
WHERE
  u.user_id = 5
AND sub1.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

So I tried to use the below:

```
 $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
    $qb->select(array(
        'sub1.totalPosts','u.username'
     ));

  $subQuery = $this->createQueryBuilder('sub1');
    $subQuery->select('SUM(totalPosts),sub1.userId')
        ->where('sub1.userId=:userId')
        ->setParameter('userId', $userId);

  $qb->from($subQuery->getDQL(),'sub1');
       ->andWhere('u.userId= :userId')
       ->setParameter('userId', $userId)
       ->groupBy('oi.orderItemId');
  return  $qb->getQuery()
               ->execute();
```

When I try to run above I get : Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_ALIASED_NAME, got 'SELECT'